# Loop Categories Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code.

```
<?php
$categories = get_categories( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'events_cat',
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order'   => 'ASC'
));
foreach ($categories as $category) ?> 
    <div>
        <?php name(); ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I try show list categories (foreach), but this no work. 
any idea why it does not work?

Comment: Missing `:` after `foreach ($categories as $category)`, it should be `foreach ($categories as $category): ?> `

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution

Add: `foreach ($categories as $category) : ?>` 
Update: `<?php echo $category->cat_name; ?>`

```
<?php
$categories = get_categories( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'events_cat',
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order'   => 'ASC'
));
foreach ($categories as $category) : ?>
    <div>
        <?php echo $category->cat_name; ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```